# Cannot create cache directory .. or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I created a new Laravel project. When I go to the terminal to install the dependecies `composer` displays the following warning:

`Cannot create cache directory /home/w3cert/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache.`

Comment: looks like composer doesn't have write permission in /home/w3cert/.composer/cache/ folder

Comment: This may also happen if you run `sudo composer self-update` on Linux, since the `~/.composer` directory will be owned by `root`, afterwards.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Change the group permission for the folder

```
sudo chown -R w3cert /home/w3cert/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org
```

and the Files folder too

```
sudo chown -R w3cert /home/w3cert/.composer/cache/files/
```

I'm assuming w3cert is your username, if not change the 4th parameter to your username.

If the problem still persists try

```
sudo chown -R w3cert /home/w3cert/.composer
```

Now, there is a chance that you won't be able to create your app directory, if that happens do the same for your html folder or the folder you are trying to create your laravel project in.

Comment: I've encountered this a couple of times, but just realised that this may be a consequence of running self-update as root:

    $ sudo composer self-update

, which may have been the cause of why the  ~/.composer folder and all  its contents change owner.

Just chown -R  your ~/.composer back to yourself

Comment: I am sure this problem started to generate right after i did `sudo composer self-update`

Comment: BTW, chown changes owner, to change group too, you have to do `w3cert:w3cert` (`[OWNER][:[GROUP]]`)

Comment: This helped me in creating project. After executing first two commands, everything went fine.

Comment: I went to the `.composer/` directory and `sudo chown $USER -R /cache` that helped.

Comment: @andkrup:  Just chown -R your ~/.composer saved my life!
And I did sudo composer too...

Comment: I'm getting this error in a window, Xampp server is there any solutions for it?

Answer (score 295):

When you installed composer pretty sure you used `$ sudo` command because of that the `~/.composer` folder was created by the root.

Run this to fix the issue:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.composer
```

Comment: Replace `$USER` with `$USER:$USER` to fix not only the user but also the group of the folder and its contents.

Comment: sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/.composer illegal group name

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Composer cache directory to a directory you have access to in CLI with `COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR` environment variable:

```
COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/var/www/composercache /usr/local/bin/composer install
```

Or you can configure it in `config` section of `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
    "cache-dir": "/var/www/composercache",
}
```