# How to update Laravel composer.json

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I included `"tymon/jwt-auth" : "~1.0.0-rc.2"` in my composer.json file.
and when I run composer update, it returns the following errors:
Cannot create cache directory `/home/mpete/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/`, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory `/home/mpete/.composer/cache/files/`, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth" : "~1.0.0-rc.2"
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37200737/11995193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the group permission for the folder

```
sudo chown -R mpete /home/mpete/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org
```

and the Files folder too

```
sudo chown -R mpete /home/mpete/.composer/cache/files/
```

If the problem still persists try

```
sudo chown -R mpete /home/w3cert/.composer
```